# Cake php - Blank screen

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

This is the problem:

I have an installation of cakephp on a server that runs apache and php (version 4).

We decided to do an upgrade from php 4 to php 5. While doing this, we decided to upgrade cakephp aswell (with a version that is compatible with php; it is 1.3.14 version).

So we downloaded the folder with CakePHP sources and deployed it onto new server along with the "old" website that wored fine on the "old" server (just copy/paste the folder into old one and kept our custom files).

Now, when I try to open a page - say "x" - I'm stuck in front of a blank page.

I've tried to read all possibile error logs (server globals php, server global apache, local to CakePHP) but there isn't a single clue in these.

Any suggestions?

*I've already deleted files into /app/tmp/cache/persistent*

Comment: have you turned an highest debug mode ?

Comment: @HaydenThring how can I do that in CakePHP? I'm pretty new to this technology.

Comment: Is this on one specific page or are all the pages blank?

Comment: Ok, i just find how to increase debug level. @Oldskool : in that page, in another there ins't a css file

Comment: Setting the debug level to 2 should help you determine the problem.

Comment: Also, make sure PHP error reporting is on, so that it displays any errors you might have to debug. Where you running a lower version than Cake 1.3 (1.2, or 1.0 maybe) before upgrading to 1.3?

Comment: Here's a [link](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1561/Migrating-from-CakePHP-1-2-to-1-3) to the migration guide for CakePHP 1.2 to 1.3, assuming you were running 1.2 before. You might want to have a look at that. The blank screen thing could be either a 500 (check your .htaccess files) or something wrong with you APP/webroot/index.php file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just resolved my problem.

Increasing debug level and changing some session's method call (session is a CakePHP object) from `del()` to `delete()`, now the page is render.

The next thing is attach css files.

Thank you all.

Comment: See https://github.com/dereuromark/upgrade/blob/master/Console/Command/UpgradeShell.php#L319

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the size of the `index.php` file at all three places becomes zero. You need to reupload them to the server.

Answer (score 0):

first, set your PHP seting on the server to display errors.
if you dont know how to do it, you can skip this first step. continue reading.

secondly, please check your webroot/index.php

my experience : i tried to copy from my WAMP server PC1 to PC2
when i checked the line 61

```
define('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH', 'C:' . DS . 'wamp3' . DS . 'www' . DS . 'cakephp' . DS . 'lib');
```

i did realize my path in PC2 is 
`wamp`
not 
`wamp3`

so just change the PATH, voila !! it runs back to fresh air :)